# Animating ListView items between two states

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation, android-listfragment

I have a `ListView` which I want to be able to toggle between two states. In the first state, all items in the list are a square shape besides some text. In the second state, all items in the list are the same except that the square shape is now a circle shape. What I want is to be able to transition the square in all visible items to a circle and vice-versa (using a `ViewSwitcher` or something like that). Anyone know whether this is possible and how I could go about implementing it? (My `ListView`'s data comes from an `ArrayAdapter`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be simpler than first thought. In the `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method of my adapter, I inflate a new `View` if `convertView` is null, and following that I find my `ViewSwitcher` from within my `View`, check the `ViewSwitcher.getDisplayedChild()` method, and call `ViewSwitcher.showNext()` or `ViewSwitcher.showNext()` as appropriate.